# Требуется здесь запятая?

Tags: запятые

Нужна ли здесь запятая, если нет, то почему?

*"Меня Саша зовут_в честь деда"* -  между "зовут" и "в".

Answer (score 2):

"В зависимости от смысла одни и те же слова могут рассматриваться или не рассматриваться как уточняющее обстоятельство".

Если "в честь деда" - уточняющее обстоятельство, нужно обособлять.

```
Меня Саша зовут, в честь деда = Меня Саша зовут, это в честь деда
```

Если это не уточнение, то не обособляется

```
Меня Саша зовут в честь деда = Сашей меня назвали в честь деда
```

В первом случае будет слышаться логическая пауза после "зовут", во втором - нет.